# How can I remove the white space below my footer and have my images resize properly?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have an image grid page to serve as links to my individual projects.

All pages look great in full browser width. However when I'm resizing, the image grid page gains a lot of extra white space below the footer, and the image grid itself does not decrease in size when resizing.

I would like to be able to resize the browser, e.g to iPad resolution, while keeping the image grid relative to the browser size and having the footer at the bottom of the page.

I've tried playing around with a few things but it has me stumped, especially as it shares similar HTML and CSS to the individual project pages, which are behaving exactly as I'd like.

**CSS:**

```
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 6rem 1fr 4rem;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

#main-container {
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.cover-images {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 265px 265px 265px;
    grid-template-columns: 420px 420px 420px;
    gap: 1.2rem;
    padding: 3.125rem 3.75rem;
}

.cover-images img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    transition: 1s;
}

.cover-images img:hover {
    filter: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.one {
    grid-row: 1 / 3;
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
}

.two {
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
}

.three {
    grid-row: 1 / 3;
    grid-column: 3 / 4;
}

.four {
    grid-row: 3 / 4;
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
}

.five {
    grid-row: 2 / 4;
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
}

.six {
    grid-row: 3 / 4;
    grid-column: 3 / 4;
}
```

**HTML:**

Home
                            Email Me

```
        <main id="main-container">
            <div class ="cover-images">
                <a class="one" href="#"><img s#"></a>
                <a class="two" href="#"><img src="#"></a>
                <a class="three" href="#"><img src="#"></a>
                <a class="four" href="#"><img src="#"></a>
                <a class="five" href="#"><img src="#"></a>
                <a class="six" href="#"><img src="#"></a>
            </div>
        </main>
```

Comment: Please add a code snippet with the HTML as well.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and you mention other pages HTML/CSS, please provide that if you think it may help

Comment: use media query and change css 'grid-row' and 'grid-column' on small screen sizes

Answer (score 0):

Ok after a few hours I've worked out a solution in case anybody has similar issues. I'm not sure whether it's characteristic of CSS Grid to not resize properly, however using a flex container solved the issue.

I created one row container and three column containers with flex values to suit the needs of the image grid, I then wrapped everything in a new flex container and set the min-height to 100vh and changed the direction to column, this created the space I needed to push the footer to the bottom of the page.

An instructional on how to build the flexbox image grid can be found here:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_grid_responsive.asp